# WCF 4 routing service throws handler error

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, routes

I am trying to use WCF 4 routing declaratively to redirect one branch of my (REST) web services to an alternate server. I configured WCF's `System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService` to route `http://oldserver:81/FileService/` calls to `http://newserver:82/FileService/`, but when I try to access the redirected service, all it does is throw the error

```
Handler "HttpLogging" has a bad module "HttpLoggingModule" in its module list
```

I can enter URLs to the new service in my browser and they work fine, but URLs to the old service (to be re-routed) fail.

I have added the following routing configuration into my web service application:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="routingConfig">
                    <!-- Specify the routing table to use. -->
                    <routing filterTableName="routingTable1" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        <!-- WCF routing table -->
        <routing>
            <filters>
                <filter name="FileFilter1" filterType="EndpointName" filterData="FileService"/>
            </filters>
            <filterTables>
                <filterTable name="routingTable1">
                    <add filterName="FileFilter1" endpointName="FileService" />
                </filterTable>
            </filterTables>
        </routing>
        <client>
            <!-- Destination endpoint defining the base URL where File messages will be routed. -->
            <endpoint name="FileService"
                      address="http://newserver:82/FileService/"
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      contract="*" />
        </client>
        <services>
            <!-- WCF routing service. -->
            <service name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService" behaviorConfiguration="routingConfig" >
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <!-- The service endpoint to be redirected. -->
                        <add baseAddress="http://oldserver:81/FileService" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <!-- Define the endpoints of the service to receive messages. -->
                <endpoint name="reqReplyEndpoint" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" address="" />
            </service>
        </services>
```

There is no longer a FileService service in the application, except the one that should be exposed by the routing service.

I've tried:

- filter types of MatchAll, EndpointAddress, and PrefixEndpointAddress;
- various forms of the old service addresses;
- different names for filters, routing tables, services;
- renaming contracts.

None of it gets my client to call the redirected service, much less even any indication that the routing service is operational or even configured at all.

How do I make the routing actually work? Failing that, how would I debug it so I can determine what to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general problem I see is that you are trying to route REST calls with Routing Service, which is not supported. MSDN reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx

> The Routing Service does not currently support routing of WCF REST
>   services. To route REST calls, consider using System.Web.Routing or
>   Application Request Routing
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164589).
>   Blockquote